# heroku keys:add error: "non-blocking socket operation could not be completed"

Tags: heroku

I'm a beginner on Ruby on Rails, Git and Heroku. I am following the Rails Tutorial behind a corporate proxy.  So far I am able to install RailsInstaller that helped me set up Ruby, Rails, and Git (also GitHub) rather smoothly. But I am really stuck on the section (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:1.4.1), where I am trying to link my public key to my new Heroku account to push the repository to Heroku.

I am on a Windows 7 box behind a corp proxy.  I have my HTTP_PROXY env variable set up and it is working for my push to GitHub. I'm not able to get past the following error. It does not seem to get to the point of complaining about ssh public key and the other posts here about heroku keys:add errors have different output..  And I haven't located relevant info at help.heroku.com. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

```
c:\Sites\testproj\thirdapp>heroku keys:add
 Enter your Heroku credentials.
 Email: my.email@gmail.com
 Password (typing will be hidden):
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

Error:     A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. (Excon::Errors::SocketError)
Backtrace: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:53:in `sysread'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:53:in `sysread'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:53:in `fill_rbuff'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:293:in `eof?'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:246:in `readline'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.14.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:68:in `initialize'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.14.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:330:in `new'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.14.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:330:in `socket'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.14.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:175:in `request_kernel'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.14.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:101:in `request'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-api-0.2.5/lib/heroku/api.rb:60:in `request'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-api-0.2.5/lib/heroku/api/login.rb:9:in `post_login'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.27.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:74:in `api_key'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.27.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:183:in `ask_for_credentials'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.27.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:214:in `ask_for_and_save_credentials'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.27.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:78:in `get_credentials'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.27.1/lib/heroku/command/keys.rb:66:in `add'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.27.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:176:in `run'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.27.1/lib/heroku/cli.rb:10:in `start'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.27.1/bin/heroku:16:in `<top (required)>'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
           C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'

Command:   heroku keys:add
Version:   heroku-gem/2.27.1 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting the same error. I uninstall it and install the lattest version of Heroku from [Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) and get resolved....

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue has been raised in:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/441

I'm also getting the same error when calling "heroku keys:add".
Unfortunately, still haven't found any workarounds when working behind proxies.

According to the issue, the command works when NOT behind a proxy.